# FileNet Component Queue with BIRT

Tags: java, birt, filenet

I'm working with IBM Case Manager and a process which requires creating reports from the cases at the end of their process. For this, I have installed a CodeModule which contains a POJO to call the BIRT Engine.

When I install the CodeModule everything is fine, but when I try to reference the CodeModule from the Component Queue, I get an error message:

```
Code Module 'undefined' cannot be accessed or the code module you selected has an invalid format.
Exception details:

org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.PlatformConfig
```

I suspected some runtime library to be missing from the maven dependencies, so I added the runtime library. The error message was still the same. I also tried creating a JAR containing all dependencies using the maven-assembly-plugin. I am sure this is not a general dependency problem, since I installed another Component Queue with PDFBox just fine.

In fear this error was caused by the BIRT reporting engine, I created a CodeModule with Jasper Report Engine, but the error message is still the same, except the error class `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource`.

I asked this question on the IBM Developer Works platform [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/337280/view.html), but the only response I got didn't help.

Comment: Are you able to turn on the log to check the full stacktrace and debug info?

Comment: I use IBM FileNet CE and PE, as well as xlxpScanner and xlxpScannerUtils libraries and included those as provided dependencies in my maven project

Comment: As an assumption: it can be libraries conflict or the libraries are not at classpath

Comment: I can't find any stack traces or debug entries in either the WebSphere logs nor the FileNet logs

Comment: I think that it maybe a problem to resolve this issue without additional information. Is it QA/stage server?

Comment: it is. I'll be able to get the logs on monday

Comment: @AlexK I found this stack trace in the pesvr_system.log http://pastebin.com/C1m1QYyp

Comment: I still haven't found out why I can't use the BIRT or Jasper classes inside my component queue, however I managed to work around it with the BIRT Web Viewer and an `HttpURLConnection` which works for my purpose

Comment: I would think that it is the way that your code module is created in the first place, are you uploading a Jar or a class? and if Jar, how is it packaged?

Comment: it's a jar, I build them with `maven package`, the folder structure should be normal: package name folders and META-INF at root level